# Unable to share video to TikTok from my app

Tags: ios, swift, tiktok

I'm using TikTok's official SDK (https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/video-kit-ios-video-kit-with-swift) to share videos from my app to TikTok. The method I use looks like this:

```
func openVideoShareMenu(fileUri: String) {
  let request = TikTokOpenSDKShareRequest()
        request.mediaType = TikTokOpenSDKShareMediaType.video
        var mediaLocalIdentifiers: [String] = []
        mediaLocalIdentifiers.append(fileUri)
        request.localIdentifiers = mediaLocalIdentifiers
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          request.send(completionBlock: { response in
            print("Response from TikTok")
          })
        }
}
```

The String `fileUri` points to an existing file and looks like this `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/83EB0771-25A6-43A5-9F9F-B859D21DB795/Documents/exportvideo.mp4`. The only thing that is happening when executing this method, is that the TikTok app opens, shows a loading animation and then immediately returns to my application. In the log I can see the following output:

```
realnote_app[25056:2173434] 8.8.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    "error_code" = "-4";
    "error_string" = "Permissions denied";
    "from_platform" = tiktoksharesdk;
    "request_id" = "3BEA07B3-19EF-46F1-90B2-8E112748CEA8";
    "response_id" = "51CEF72B-D265-449C-929B-372F2401AA7C";
    "share_state" = 20003;
}
```

Where the `error_code` -4 means `Auth denied.` and the `share_state` 20003 means `Not enough permissions to operation.` but I'm currently login in into TikTok. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey do you get any solution for this i am also facing the same problem

Comment: Nope, still nothing

Comment: it works for me now you have to use the correct TikTokAppID

Comment: I have similar issue with login with Tiktok on IOS, everything is working file on android, Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    additionalPermissions = "user.info.basic";
    code = "j7qa_oX07hahNAFGkJhjICKcRR6XvvVuejc5GLxisMBpmBIEgv3L4EW_-n7PuBEFcuaCU92_EBLwxqSr76YcGze6Z0FiVEt_UXvtr9mNsp1nw5SsjzrAc0vXORfas65w*1!6400";
    "error_code" = 0;
    "from_platform" = tiktokopensdk;
    "request_id" = "A0CB93D7-EE5E-4F55-9AA9-45A40F6E8C56";
    "response_id" = "A0CB93D7-EE5E-4F55-9AA9-45A40F6E8C56";
    state = "";
}

Comment: For me the issue was related on the Appdelegeate `TikTokOpenSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)` must be added

Comment: So can I provide to it any local url path, or it has to be from the photo library?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget this step:

> Then add Share Kit to your app by navigating to the Manage apps page,
> and clicking + Add products.

[image]

Comment: I thought I was approved but I actually wasn't. You might even need to resubmit your app after adding Share Kit.

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing the same issue that you mentioned above. You have to convert your local `uri` path to `PHAsset` and then send it to Tiktok for sharing otherwise it won't work.

```
func shareVideoToTiktok(args : [String: Any?],result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    let videoFile = args["videoFile"] as? String
    let redirectUrl = args["redirectUrl"] as? String
    let fileType = args["fileType"] as? String
    let videoData = try? Data(contentsOf:  URL(fileURLWithPath: videoFile!)) as NSData
    

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({

        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
        let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(Date().description)" + (fileType == "image" ? ".jpeg" : ".mp4")

        videoData!.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
        if fileType == "image" {
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))

        }else {
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))

        }
    },
    completionHandler: { success, error in

        if success {

            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fileType == "image" ? .image : .video, options: fetchOptions)

            if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject {
                let localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
                let shareRequest = TikTokShareRequest(localIdentifiers: [localIdentifier], mediaType: fileType == "image" ? .image : .video, redirectURI: redirectUrl!)
                shareRequest.shareFormat = .normal
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    shareRequest.send()
                    result("success")
                }
            }
        }
        else if let error = error {

            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {

            result("Error getting the files!")
        }
    })
}
```

More information over here - https://github.com/tiktok/tiktok-opensdk-ios/issues/22